# Digital Filtering

Tags: filter, dsp

Lets say I have an audio signal and want to filter out anything below 100 Hertz. At first, I would think of a high-pass filter. A simple capacitor could do the job, but there are going to still be those frequencies just at a lower amplitude. If I totally wanted to filter out everything below 100 Hertz, and totally allow everything above, I have heard digital filtering is the solution.

How does this work and what is a practical way it could be done? I don't have a particular application in mind but I am curious to conceptually how digital filters work?

Comment: A perfect brick wall filter is physically impossible. We can get close with FIR filters. This is where all the math you don't know yet lives. The real question is how much stop band attenuation your application really needs.

Comment: I don't have a particular application, I just was curious

Comment: Even in Digital or analog signals, a perfect filter is impossible. In digital signal processing, you can work with FIR filters with windowing.

Comment: @skyler, based on your comment I just edited the question to make it clearer you're after a bit of a generic explanation rather than a specific design. Hopefully you're OK with the changes but it not you can always roll it back.

Comment: Lots of higher maths (complex numbers, integration, Fourier transform) is involved to specify the the taps of a [Finite Impulse Response filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response). You may want to search the web for that a bit or ask a specific question about it here.

Answer (score 1):

There is a neat mathematical trick called Fourier transformation - any signal can be represented as a sum of sinusoids of different frequencies. By doing this, time series signal is converted to a frequency domain representation. The trick extends to a fact that both time domain and frequency domain representations are equivalent - you can convert back from frequency domain to time domain and get your original signal. Well, there are some limitations, because your time domain signal is discrete and finite, but let's not go there.

What digital filters do is they convert time domain signal into frequency domain, then drop unwanted frequencies and convert back to time domain - that's internal working. In reality algorithms don't do exactly that. Because of a fair amount of mathematical shortcuts that can be taken, in the end you just continuously multiply your incomming signal by an array of digits (filter kernel) to get an effect of going to frequency domain and back.

I would suggest reading this book - [The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to
Digital Signal Processing](http://www.dspguide.com/pdfbook.htm) by Steven W. Smith because I can't give a better explanation than you can find there.